# how to build word2vec content based recommendation?

Tags: recommender-system, similarity, python-3.x

I am building a content-based recommendation system for hotel accommodation. I have a hotel name, hotel description and location. I combined hotel name, description and location. Then, applied NLP and converted into vectors using TF-IDF.

I am taking hotel name and location as an input and recommend the hotel based on cosine similarity. I wanted to use word2vec instead of TF-IDF and make a recommendation. Anyone can suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can find a number of blogs teaching the use of [Word2Vec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word2vec),

- [Introduction to Word Embedding and Word2Vec](https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-word-embedding-and-word2vec-652d0c2060fa)
- [A Beginner's Guide to Word2Vec and Neural Word Embeddings](https://pathmind.com/wiki/word2vec)

If you are building a hotel recommendation system, I think the name of the hotel is not a good feature. Users are less concerned with the name of the hotel than its location or description provided.

- You can take a small description from the user and the location in which they would like to search for the hotel. Using [Doc2Vec](https://towardsdatascience.com/understand-how-to-transfer-your-paragraph-to-vector-by-doc2vec-1e225ccf102), convert the description ( text ) into a fixed-sized vector ( embedding ). Find a hotel whose description is the most similar to the one provided by the user ( maybe using Cosine Similarity or any other measures ).
- Before this find a hotel that is close to the location provided by the user ( say a hotel which lies in a radius of 2 km from the given location ).

Using these two factors, you can prepare a list of hotels whose location and description match the user's needs.